# Advanced link category functionality in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've been fiddling around with Wordpress and I've realised that the links and link categories provide very little functionality.

For example, I want to display all the links in a certain link category in one page, and not any of the other links.
And in the remaining pages I want to display every link except those that have said category.

I can think of a dumb way of doing it, using a simple "Text Widget" and doing the list in HTML, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way. Like a way of being able to select which link categories I want displayed on a "Links" widget. A way to have several such widgets would also be great to divide the links among more than one sidebar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter links based on the link category, so if you had a category foo you could get all links that were inside foo by using.

`<?php wp_list_bookmarks('title_li=&categorize=0&category_name=foo' ); ?>`

Foo can also be a varible, so you could figure out which page you were on and filter you list based on the title. In this case if I were on a post or page called bar the output would be all the links in the bar category.

`<?php wp_list_bookmarks('title_li=&categorize=0&category_name='.$post->post_title ); ?>`

Comment: So, that means I can't use the provided "Links" widget and have to use "Text" widgets and drop the PHP in there? Or create my own widget?

Comment: I'm not sure about widgets, but it's fairly straightforward to modify the actual template files.